# Extend an existing Context Menu inside Eclipse Outline View for Xtext

Tags: eclipse, xtext, outline-view

We have an eclipse plugin which has been created using Xtext. And now I want to add a context menu to an Element inside the Outline View inside Eclipse. I understand that I need to have a menuContribution which will invoke a Command. But what I dont understand is, do I have to create (define) a command in some way or the other.
My plugin.xml contains an extension point for *"org.eclipse.ui.menus"*.

Menu Contribution is something like this:

I find tutorials that talk about creating menu contributions, but there is nothing which will tie up my menuContribution to a command I want to define.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you will need three extensions:

- `org.eclipse.ui.command`
- `org.eclipse.ui.handlers`
- `org.eclipse.ui.menu`

It requires some fidling to get them right. I suggest you look at some open source code and starts from there.
Introduction article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html

The `locationUri` of the context menu you like to contribute to should be `popup:org.eclipse.xtext.ui.outline.OutlinePageContextMenu`. Found here: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-eclipse/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext.ui/src/org/eclipse/xtext/ui/editor/outline/impl/OutlinePage.java